# Validation of dropdownlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, drop-down-menu

I need help to validate my dropdownlist value using javascript.

Here is my HTML :

```html
<select name="users" id="users" />
   <option value="test" style="color:#ccc;">Select user</option>
   <option value="user1">1</option>
   <option value="user2">2</option>
   <option value="user3">3</option>   
</select>
```

And my javascript (using another page)

```js
function validateForm() {

 var x = document.forms["frmAccessDemand"]["users"].value;
     if (x == "test") {
         alert("Please select one user");
         return false;
     }
  }
```

But that's not working. I tried using .text instead of .value  but same result.
I also tried .selectedindex = 0 ... same result :(

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You have a self-closing `<select>` tag. remove the forward slash after `id="users"`:

change

```
<select name="users" id="users" />
```

into

```
<select name="users" id="users">
```